# Can't click dynamically loaded radio button on Windows Phone 8.1 Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8.1

I load dynamically part of my web site with jQuery. On every browser it works fine, but on Windows Phone 8.1 Internet Explorer loaded radiobuttons don't respond. The can't be checked, but they are not greyed out (inactive). There are no jQuery events bound to this radiobuttons. Issue confirmed on two Windows Phones. What to do?

```
 $('#paymentsResult').fadeTo('slow', 0.1, function () {
            $('#paymentsResult').load(url, function (data) {
                if (data == "{}") {
                        $('.PaymentAccordion').hide();
                }
                else {
                    $('.PaymentAccordion').show();
                }

                $('#paymentsResult').fadeTo('slow', 1);
            });
        });
```

The result of this code is:

```
 <tr class="table-valign-middle">
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input name="ChoosenPaymentId" class="RadioButtonPayment" id="ChoosenPaymentId" style="vertical-align: top;" type="radio" checked="checked" value="47353a36-6fe4-e411-80c8-000c2990a869">
                    <span>Cash</span>
                </label>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-valign-middle">
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input name="ChoosenPaymentId" class="RadioButtonPayment" id="ChoosenPaymentId" style="vertical-align: top;" type="radio" value="36153b58-6fe4-e411-80c8-000c2990a869">
                    <span>Credit</span>
                </label>

            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that I had to wrapp each checkbox with `<div class="radio"></div>`
So now my code look like this:

```
 <tr class="table-valign-middle">
        <td>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input name="ChoosenPaymentId" class="RadioButtonPayment" id="ChoosenPaymentId" style="vertical-align: top;" type="radio" checked="checked" value="47353a36-6fe4-e411-80c8-000c2990a869">
                <span>Cash</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-valign-middle">
        <td>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input name="ChoosenPaymentId" class="RadioButtonPayment" id="ChoosenPaymentId" style="vertical-align: top;" type="radio" value="36153b58-6fe4-e411-80c8-000c2990a869">
                <span>Credit</span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I don't know it's Bootstrap related issue or my Boostrap theme. 
Im using WrapBootrap Color Admin theme.